# How do i correct the Transform Component error?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I created the code for destroying it when it collides with the obstacle but the problem is when it collides with the obstacle it get destroyed but one error is coming about Transform component.

> MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'Transform' has been
> destroyed but you are still trying to access it. Your script should
> either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object.
> UnityEngine.Transform.get_position () followplayer.Update ()

Comment: Show your code please ... apparently you are trying to access an option that has been destroyed as the message says ;) So if you somewhere destroy according object you should do e.g. `if(theObject) { var position = theObject.transform.position; ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Could you show your script? Before that, I guess you should try this:

```
if (gameObject != null)
    //Destroy your object
```

I guess you wrote your code in the Unity update function so this code is running every frame. In other words, it tries to destroy your object even after it's destroyed and becomes null. If you will ask the compiler if it's null before you destroy it, the compiler will not try to destroy your object after it's already destroyed.